# Drupal EntityMalformedException

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting this issue

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7922 of /opt/prolifics/includes/common.inc)

whenever cron runs in Drupal-7. Can anyone help me on this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fun Drupal problem. It generally relates to malformed or orphaned field entities. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-6891428 for a potential fix